# Symfony2 Translation Parameters inside config.yml(parameters.yml)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing a web app, and I want to use parameters for translation files, like the parameters for twig, because I have some variables that I use in multiple translations.

For example the site name. I already use Twig Global variables, but I also use the translator inside services, and I don't want to inject the container or the variables to these services.

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
        sitename: %sitename%
        ....
```

Is something like that possible for translations?

Comment: Nope. Translating is a simple str_replace within the translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment Pazi, in effect it's not possible to do that, in my case I can use the normal twig translate parameters like:

**config.yml**

```
 twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
        sitename: %sitename%
```

**index.html.twig**

```
 <h1 class="heading">{% trans with {'%sitename%': sitename } %} Mybundle.hello {% endtrans %}</h1>
```

and for translations inside services I can inject them like:

```
my_bundle.my_service:
    class: %my_bundle.my_service.class%
    arguments: [@doctrine, @translator, %sitename%]
    public: true
```